# Why I get Unexpected token export Error on nodejs with vue cli and ssr?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, vue-ssr

I just created a vue project using the vue/cli v3.10.0

I add `ssr` to the project like [vue-cli-ssr-example](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-cli-ssr-example) example.

But after I build and run the server side (nodejs) and I try to browse to `http://localhost:8080`:

But The following error occurs :

```
error during render : /
C:\sandbox3\vuecli-with-ssr\node_modules\register-service-worker\index.js:18
export function register (swUrl, hooks) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
error during render : /favicon.ico
C:\sandbox3\vuecli-with-ssr\node_modules\register-service-worker\index.js:18
export function register (swUrl, hooks) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

**Steps to reproduce**

```
$ Clone my github repo: git clone https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr.git

$ npm i

$ npm run build:prod && node server.js

$ open http://localhost:8080/
```

Here [My Github repo code](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr) and this is how I create my repo:

1. First I create a new app using vue/cli: `$ vue create vuecli-with-ssr`
   [image]
2. I edit and add the files: [vue.config.js](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/vue.config.js)
   [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/tsconfig.json)
   [server.js](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/server.js)
   [babel.config.js](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/babel.config.js)
   [entry-client.ts](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/src/entry-client.ts)
   [entry-server.ts](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/src/entry-server.ts)
   [main.ts](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/src/main.ts)
   [index.template.html](https://github.com/wizardnet972/vuecli-with-ssr/blob/master/src/index.template.html)
3. Run the project in production mode (**not the dev server**) : `npm run build:prod && node server.js`

Any help would be appreciated.